# text will not center in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains inside 3 'floated' divs.  The containing div has a line of text. The three floating inner divs also have a line of text.

When I specify text-align center for the outermost containing div, the three nested divs appear first, on one row next to each other left-to-right, and THEN the containing div's text appears to the right of the contained divs, centered in the space to the right of them.

Instead, I don't understand why the outermost containing div's text will not appear centered in the browser window, then below that the 3 contained divs and their text would appear.  That's what I need to happen.

Here is the code.  By the way I tried to embed a .jpg image into this question so you can see the problem -- anyone know how to display a screenshot or .jpg into a question here?

```
<head>

<style>
#myRowStyles
{
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:100px;
  background-color:#b0e0e6;
  border: 1px solid red;
}       

#leftSide
{
  width:120px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#centerPiece
{
  width:120px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#rightSide
{
  width:120px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>


<div id="myRowStyles"><b>THIS IS THE TOP OF THE ROW</b>
   <div id="leftSide">  LEFT SIDE -- Leftie
   </div>
   <div id="centerPiece"> Centerpiece, Folks.
   </div>
   <div id="rightSide">  All Righty -- RIGHT SIDE
   </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both">
</div>
<div id="myRowStyles"><b>THIS IS ROW #2</b>
   <div id="leftSide">  LEFT SIDE -- Leftie
   </div>
   <div id="centerPiece"> Centerpiece, Folks.
   </div>
   <div id="rightSide">  All Righty -- RIGHT SIDE
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to center all the text?

Comment: Hi jc, I just wanted the text of the outermost containing div centered in the browser window and above the three inner contained divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that to make divs behave like tables you must define the display attributes in CSS:

```
#container {
display: table;
}

#row  {
display: table-row;
}

#left, #right, #middle {
display: table-cell;
}
```

So you will also need to add an extra `<div>` at the beginning for the container. I haven't tested this.

Also, I dont think you can make a single row span 3 columns when using DIVs so you must do something like this:

```
<head>

<style>

#container {
  width:90%;
  float:center;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align:centre;
  display: table;
}

#myRowStyles
{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#b0e0e6;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-row;

}       

#leftSide,#centerPiece,#rightSide
{
  width:120px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;

}
</style>
</head>

<div id="container">
<div id="myRowStyles">
   <div id="leftSide"> 
   </div>
   <div id="centerPiece"> Row 1
   </div>
   <div id="rightSide"> 
   </div>
</div>
<div id="myRowStyles">
   <div id="leftSide">  LEFT SIDE -- Leftie
   </div>
   <div id="centerPiece"> Centerpiece, Folks.
   </div>
   <div id="rightSide">  All Righty -- RIGHT SIDE
   </div>
</div>


<div id="myRowStyles">
   <div id="leftSide"> 
   </div>
   <div id="centerPiece"> Row 2
   </div>
   <div id="rightSide"> 
   </div>
</div>
<div id="myRowStyles">
   <div id="leftSide">  LEFT SIDE -- Leftie
   </div>
   <div id="centerPiece"> Centerpiece, Folks.
   </div>
   <div id="rightSide">  All Righty -- RIGHT SIDE
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post an answer if you're unsure whether it works.  Also FYI, certain versions of IE will not work with `display:table`.

Comment: Was just trying to help. Apologies for that, I wasn't aware that it didn't work with certain versions of IE. I've edited and tested the above code, and it appears to work (Safari).

Comment: Hi all, I really appreciate your help here!  I've been messing with it for 1/2 the day before raising the white flag for help and as usual you guys have really come through, thanks to everyone, I'm not quite there, but Sooper's idea led me to what I believe is the best way -- I now have the text I wanted centered above the other 3 divs no longer containing them -- it is just another div that sits above the 3 floating divs.  Then I followed Sooper's advice and added a new containing div for the browser-centered text and the three divs beneath it floating in one row -- I'll post the code soon.

Answer (score 2):

First you have multiple same ID's on the page.  That's bad.  Change them to classes.

Second give myRowStyles a width.

Comment: Hi, I tried width=100px and width=400px and even width=100% on myRowStyles used by the outermost div, this still does not center the outermost containing div's text in the middle of the browser window and above the 3 inner divs

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/We74E/2/

Comment: Simon it looks great in jsfiddle but I copied your first myRowStyles and tried it in Firefox 8.0 then I tried your second one and in Firefox it does not look like it does in jsfiddle, and I'm running this StackOverflow session (and hence your link to jsfiddle) in Windows Explorer, maybe that's why.

Comment: Have you notice i replace the id with classes?